# Unable to configure safety settings in gemini-pro: google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument

Tags: python, google-gemini

The code below runs find but when I uncomment any of the safety settings it throws:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Request contains an invalid argument
```

The reason I'm trying to customize the safety settings is because in a real scenario gemini-pro is throwing me an error: response was blocked. This happens when I'm trying to use it to generate SQL.

```
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel
from vertexai.preview import generative_models

safety_config = {
        #generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        #generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        #generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        #generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_LOW_AND_ABOVE,
        #generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
        #generative_models.HarmCategory.HARM_CATEGORY_UNSPECIFIED: generative_models.HarmBlockThreshold.BLOCK_NONE,
}

model = GenerativeModel(
    "gemini-pro",
    safety_settings=safety_config
)


response = model.generate_content("What is the future of AI in one sentence?")
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your safety settings is in correct try this.

```
GOOGLE_API_KEY=userdata.get('GOOGLE_API_KEY')
genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

generation_config: str ={
      'temperature': 0.9,
      'top_p': 1,
      'top_k': 40,
      'max_output_tokens': 2048,
      'stop_sequences': [],
      }

    safety_settings : list[str] = [{"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
                    {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
                    {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"},
                    {"category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT", "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"}]

    
model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name='gemini-pro',
                                  generation_config=self.generation_config,
                                  safety_settings=self.safety_settings
                                  )

response = model.generate_content("What is the meaning of life?")

print(response.text)
```

Pro tip: if your having issues just remove generation_config and safety_settings they aren't required and you can just use the default.